# Copy contents of a Unix File to Postgres Table column

Tags: postgresql, shell, unix, awk, psql

I have a requirement where I am receiving a XML file on a Unix path. I want to copy the content of this xml file in a Postgres table in one column.

Example file received at : /home/bojack/test.xml

```
<address>
   <street>Main Street</street>
   <city>New York</city>
   <country>USA</country>
</address>
```

Want to copy this to a table with 2 columns,

```
id value
1  <address>
   <street>Main Street</street>
   <city>New York</city>
   <country>US</country>
   </address>
```

Could anyone please help on this?

Comment: You want to put the whole file into a single table cell with newlines? Is that `id` column type `serial` or does the previous maximum `id` value need to be read from the table before loading? Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: I want to put whole file in single table cell(no newline needed, simple dump). I am getting only one file per day, so.. id will not matter, it would be only 1. I tried using ETL tool, informatica (File to Table transform) but not getting expected result.

Comment: [XML type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-xml.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the table:

```
# CREATE TABLE test_table(id serial, value text); -- notice id type serial
CREATE TABLE
```

Then, let's add a random attribute to an element (just to demonstrate quotes in the content):

```
$ cat file
<address>
   <street some="attribute">Main Street</street><!--attribute here-->
   <city>New York</city>
   <country>USA</country>
</address>
```

Now some awk to slurp in the whole file, to duplicate all double quotes in the content and to add (or replace all) double quotes to the beginning and end:

```
$ awk '                   # tested with gawk, mawk and awk version 20121220
BEGIN {
    RS="^$"               # slurp in the whole file
}
{
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"")      # double the double quotes
    # gsub(/\r?\n/,"")    # to remove newlines, uncomment (untested)
    gsub(/^"*|"*$/,"\"")  # add quotes to the beginning and end
    print                 # output
}' file
```

Output with above awk (notice `"`s in the beginning and the end and `""`s in the middle):

```
"<address>
   <street some=""attribute"">Main Street</street>
   <city>New York</city>
   <country>USA</country>
</address>
"
```

Now to process the file with awk and to feed it's output to psql:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{gsub(/"/,"\"\"");gsub(/^"*|"*$/,"\"");print}' file |
> psql -h host -d dbname -c "\copy test_table(value) from '/dev/stdin' csv" -U username
Password: 
COPY 1
```

And finally:

```
# select * from test_table ;
 id |                      value                       
----+--------------------------------------------------
  1 | <address>                                       +
    |    <street some="attribute">Main Street</street>+
    |    <city>New York</city>                        +
    |    <country>USA</country>                       +
    | </address>                                      +
    | 
(1 row)
```

This was tested in Linux using Bash shell.